# Google Data Studio - Separating values within string

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have a Google Spreadsheet linked to Data Studio and one of the columns has a comma separated list of values (example: book,car,house)

Within Data Studio you can output that row however I'd like to be able to split each value to be individually searchable/filter.

I've not come across anything that seems to make this possible without having to modify the spreadsheet which I'd prefer not to do. Is there any way within Data Studio to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own customized [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/) that will do this. In the connector code, this field will have to be parsed into separate fields. You can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to do that.